# C++ Win32 - Window closes on startup

Tags: c++, winapi

Here is a pretty clean window with just an edit box (The handle to the windows are in my GameLibrary.h) but I have created many windows before and it worked fine now I can't for the life of me find out why the window opens and closes.

I was looking at my WndProc and checking if anything was leaking into the DestroyWindow message but nope. Can someone give me a fresh pair of eyes and tell me what may be the cause of this problem? Thanks!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "GameLibrary.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK LoginWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow) {

    //Attributes for the Login Class
    wchar_t szLoginWindowClassName[] = L"GameLauncherLogin";
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASSW LoginWindowClass;

    LoginWindowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    LoginWindowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    LoginWindowClass.hbrBackground = HBRUSH(GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
    LoginWindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ARROW));
    LoginWindowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
    LoginWindowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    LoginWindowClass.lpfnWndProc = LoginWndProc;
    LoginWindowClass.lpszClassName = szLoginWindowClassName;
    LoginWindowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    LoginWindowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    if (!RegisterClass(&LoginWindowClass)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Class was not able to register!", L"Class Registration Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    }

    hLoginWindow = CreateWindow(szLoginWindowClassName, L"GameLibrary Login", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 500, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (hLoginWindow == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    ShowWindow(hLoginWindow, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hLoginWindow);

    if (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

This is the WndProc.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LoginWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

        switch (uMessage) {

        case WM_CREATE: {
            hUsername = CreateWindow(L"Edit", L"Test", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 5, 5, 5, 5, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            break;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY: {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }

        default: {
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMessage, wParam, lParam);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `break` for `WM_CREATE`, instead of `return`, is ungood. And maybe `DefWindowProc` return logical fail value for `WM_CREATE`. Anyway, take charge.

Comment: Other general advice: when using C++, code at the C++ level. The C-isms and Microsoft-isms just make the code more verbose and less clear.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: There is not a single line in the code that could be changed to make the code more C++-ish. The `MSG` and `WNDCLASSW` structures could be properly zero-initialized, but then, that's not strictly C++ either. Which *"C-isms"* and *"Microsoft-isms"* would you suggest getting rid of, and what do you propose as a replacement?

Comment: The C-isms include (1) forward-declaring functions, (2) not using `const`, (3) using `NULL` instead of `nullptr` and `0`, (4) declaring variables long before they're needed, (5) not checking for failures, and introducing errors where that's done, generally by not using C++ exceptions. The Microsoft-isms include the silly and annoying Hungarian notation prefixes that were in support of the help system in Microsoft's Programmer's Workbench in the 1980's (talk about archaic, heh), and they include the `WinMain` monstrosity instead of a standard `main` function. My answer was 2 short for SO, sry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message loop should be ... a loop !

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
```

Comment: Oh my jesus! Thank you so much! I was actually doing something at the time as was thinking of an if statement while I was writing this. 

#NoobStatus